# Why don't random numbers in AWK change after the first run?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, awk

I'm studying [AWK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK), and when I use the following command for the second time why are the numbers always the same?

First time run:

```
awk 'BEGIN{for(i=1;i<=10;i++) print int(101*rand())}'
24
29
85
15
59
19
81
17
48
15
```

Second time run:

```
awk 'BEGIN{for(i=1;i<=10;i++) print int(101*rand())}'
24
29
85
15
59
19
81
17
48
15
```

Comment: [`RFC 1149.5 specifies 4 as the standard IEEE-vetted random number`.](http://xkcd.com/221/)

Comment: Took them five revisions to settle for the obvious choice.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Numeric-Functions.html

> **CAUTION**: In most awk implementations, including gawk, `rand()` starts generating numbers from the same starting number, or seed, each time you run awk. Thus, a program generates the same results each time you run it. The numbers are random within one awk run but predictable from run to run. This is convenient for debugging, but if you want a program to do different things each time it is used, you must change the seed to a value that is different in each run. To do this, use `srand()`.

Comment: Just be sure to use `srand()` only once per run, not once per call to `rand()`. The other pitfall I've seen is to use `srand(time())` in a program that could be run more than once in the same second, hence still getting the same seed in all instances started that second.

Comment: fore informations, this doesn't happen in mawk 1.3.3

Comment: Example (random lines): `awk 'BEGIN { srand() }; rand() < 0.01' file.txt`

Comment: awk 'BEGIN { "date +%N" | getline seed; srand(seed); print rand(); }';

Using nanoseconds as seed